# Importando biblioteca no python

Tags: python, pycharm

Não estou conseguindo importar qualquer biblioteca no python usando o pycharm. Quando digito, por exemplo, o comando `import time`, as palavras ficam cinza e não traz nada.

Comment: E você utilizou o módulo `time` em algum lugar do código?

Comment: Tem uma imagem do que ocorre Rafael?

Comment: Geralmente isso é uma forma grafica do pycharm dizer que você não utilizou essa importação... Se vc não utilizar o pacote time no arquivo .py em questão, ele vai continuar 'cinza'.

Answer (score 1):

Quando a importação fica em cinza, é porque você não está usando ela.

O que suspeito que você esteja fazendo é o seguinte:

```
import time
sleep(2)
```

Isso não funciona porque você está importando só o nome `time`. Pra usar a biblioteca, é necessário acessar suas funções assim:

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

Ou, importando todos os nomes do módulo, do seguinte jeito:

```
from time import *
sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o @Haynesss comentou, o PyCharm indica toda vez que uma variável ou mesmo um import não for utilizado. É uma boa prática.

De qualquer forma, como bônus, é sempre interessante definir qual o interpretador python você está usando no PyCharm.

Dê uma olhada [na documentação do PyCharm quanto a configuração de interpretador python](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html). Está inglês, mas é um ponto de partida.